# xHCI controller failure with USB2 audio interface

Tags: 18.04, usb, sound, performance, xhci-hcd

I'm trying to get Native Instruments KOMPLETE Audio 1 working in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS with kernel 5.4.0-52-generic.

It's a regular USB2 audio interface and I'm connecting it to an USB3 port.
Except for a mouse and keyboard, there's nothing else connected to any other USB3 ports.
According to a USB3 tester, it uses 5.1 V at about 450 mA.

While I've used it from Arch Linux before, Ubuntu keeps disabling the device. In order to use it again, I need to plug it out and plug it into a different USB port. Then it would work again for maybe a minute or so, until Ubuntu disables it again. From time to time, Ubuntu reduces the bandwidth and power-cycles the device.

Snippets from dmesg:

```
[ 2504.565959] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 2504.810303] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1830, bcdDevice= 0.13
[ 2504.810306] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[ 2504.810308] usb 1-2: Product: Komplete Audio 1
[ 2504.810309] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Native Instruments
[ 2504.810310] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00001A23
[ 2504.850627] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[ 2507.443820] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[ 2508.820927] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 2 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2508.820930] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 2 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2508.820931] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 2 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2508.820933] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 2 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2508.820934] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 2 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2508.820935] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 2 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2508.821310] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 2 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2508.821643] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 2 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2529.801389] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 2530.122630] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 2530.367602] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1830, bcdDevice= 0.13
[ 2530.367604] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[ 2530.367606] usb 1-2: Product: Komplete Audio 1
[ 2530.367607] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Native Instruments
[ 2530.367609] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00001A23
[ 2533.961277] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 3 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2533.961280] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 3 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2533.961282] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 3 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2533.961283] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 3 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2533.961688] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 3 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2533.961689] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 3 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2533.961691] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 3 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2533.962137] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 3 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2538.107982] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: ERROR unknown event type 37
[ 2538.841453] perf: interrupt took too long (2999 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 66500
[ 2554.539607] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 2554.827290] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 2555.451571] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2555.788305] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[ 2556.135325] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 2556.591939] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1830, bcdDevice= 0.13
[ 2556.591942] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[ 2556.591943] usb 1-2: Product: Komplete Audio 1
[ 2556.591944] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Native Instruments
[ 2556.591945] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00001A23
[ 2556.664311] usb 1-2: parse_audio_format_rates_v2v3(): unable to find clock source (clock -71)
[ 2556.700404] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x201, wIndex = 0xa00, type = 4
[ 2556.700408] usb 1-2: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
[ 2556.709288] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x200, wIndex = 0xa00, type = 4
[ 2556.709291] usb 1-2: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
[ 2556.718289] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x201, wIndex = 0xb00, type = 4
[ 2556.718292] usb 1-2: 11:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 11)
[ 2556.721326] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x200, wIndex = 0xb00, type = 4
[ 2556.721329] usb 1-2: 11:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 11)
[ 2556.740712] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 2557.019351] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 2557.367593] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2557.891600] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2558.547421] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 2558.724217] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1830, bcdDevice= 0.13
[ 2558.724220] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[ 2558.724221] usb 1-2: Product: Komplete Audio 1
[ 2558.724223] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Native Instruments
[ 2558.724224] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00001A23
[ 2560.578047] usb 1-2: 1:1: cannot set freq 192000 (v2/v3): err -71
[ 2560.587795] usb 1-2: parse_audio_format_rates_v2v3(): unable to find clock source (clock -71)
[ 2560.623776] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x201, wIndex = 0xa00, type = 4
[ 2560.623779] usb 1-2: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
[ 2560.632808] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x200, wIndex = 0xa00, type = 4
[ 2560.632811] usb 1-2: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
[ 2560.641742] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x201, wIndex = 0xb00, type = 4
[ 2560.641745] usb 1-2: 11:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 11)
[ 2560.644879] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x200, wIndex = 0xb00, type = 4
[ 2560.644882] usb 1-2: 11:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 11)
[ 2560.664015] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 2560.935603] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 2561.112468] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1830, bcdDevice= 0.13
[ 2561.112470] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[ 2561.112471] usb 1-2: Product: Komplete Audio 1
[ 2561.112472] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Native Instruments
[ 2561.112473] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00001A23
[ 2563.741297] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 8 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2563.741301] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 8 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2563.741302] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 8 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2563.741304] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 8 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2563.741706] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 8 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2563.741708] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 8 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2563.741709] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 8 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2563.741752] retire_capture_urb: 44 callbacks suppressed
[ 2563.742089] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 8 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2563.830877] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[ 2563.830994] usb 1-2: cannot submit urb (err = -19)
[ 2563.831731] usb 1-2: cannot submit urb (err = -19)
[ 2564.127567] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 2564.371985] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1830, bcdDevice= 0.13
[ 2564.371988] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[ 2564.371989] usb 1-2: Product: Komplete Audio 1
[ 2564.371991] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Native Instruments
[ 2564.371992] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00001A23
[ 2567.962866] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 9 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2567.962869] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 9 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2567.963295] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 9 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2567.963297] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 9 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2567.963298] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 9 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2567.963299] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 9 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2567.963300] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 9 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2567.963832] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 9 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2572.345491] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: ERROR unknown event type 37
[ 2572.348412] retire_capture_urb: 284 callbacks suppressed
[ 2575.061363] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 10
[ 2575.347837] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[ 2575.592653] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1830, bcdDevice= 0.13
[ 2575.592656] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[ 2575.592658] usb 1-2: Product: Komplete Audio 1
[ 2575.592659] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Native Instruments
[ 2575.592661] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00001A23
[ 2576.652758] usb 1-2: 1:1: cannot set freq 192000 (v2/v3): err -71
[ 2576.661794] usb 1-2: parse_audio_format_rates_v2v3(): unable to find clock source (clock -71)
[ 2576.697773] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x201, wIndex = 0xa00, type = 4
[ 2576.697777] usb 1-2: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
[ 2576.706783] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x200, wIndex = 0xa00, type = 4
[ 2576.706786] usb 1-2: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
[ 2576.715769] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x201, wIndex = 0xb00, type = 4
[ 2576.715772] usb 1-2: 11:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 11)
[ 2576.718730] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x200, wIndex = 0xb00, type = 4
[ 2576.718733] usb 1-2: 11:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 11)
[ 2576.737076] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 2578.133138] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[ 2578.264660] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2578.472550] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2578.683917] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 12, error -71
[ 2579.020038] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 2579.196963] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1830, bcdDevice= 0.13
[ 2579.196965] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[ 2579.196967] usb 1-2: Product: Komplete Audio 1
[ 2579.196969] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Native Instruments
[ 2579.196970] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00001A23
[ 2579.742192] usb 1-2: parse_audio_format_rates_v2v3(): unable to find clock source (clock -71)
[ 2579.778179] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x201, wIndex = 0xa00, type = 4
[ 2579.778183] usb 1-2: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
[ 2579.787165] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x200, wIndex = 0xa00, type = 4
[ 2579.787168] usb 1-2: 10:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 10)
[ 2579.796145] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x201, wIndex = 0xb00, type = 4
[ 2579.796148] usb 1-2: 11:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 11)
[ 2579.799118] usb 1-2: cannot get ctl value: req = 0x83, wValue = 0x200, wIndex = 0xb00, type = 4
[ 2579.799120] usb 1-2: 11:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 11)
[ 2579.817374] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 13
[ 2580.095986] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[ 2580.308198] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[ 2580.664974] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=17cc, idProduct=1830, bcdDevice= 0.13
[ 2580.664977] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[ 2580.664978] usb 1-2: Product: Komplete Audio 1
[ 2580.664980] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Native Instruments
[ 2580.664981] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 00001A23
[ 2583.303797] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 15 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2583.303799] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 15 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2583.304233] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 15 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2583.304234] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 15 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2583.304235] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 15 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2583.304236] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 15 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2583.304237] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 15 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2583.304294] retire_capture_urb: 43 callbacks suppressed
[ 2583.304720] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: WARN: buffer overrun event for slot 15 ep 4 on endpoint
[ 2584.046654] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: ERROR unknown event type 37
[ 2589.284242] usb 1-2: timeout: still 4 active urbs on EP #81
[ 2590.292245] usb 1-2: timeout: still 12 active urbs on EP #1
[ 2591.292291] usb 1-2: timeout: still 4 active urbs on EP #81
[ 2592.292285] usb 1-2: timeout: still 12 active urbs on EP #1
[ 2593.508499] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[ 2593.508669] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[ 2593.508696] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[ 2593.508709] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[ 2593.508894] usb 1-2: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 0
[ 2593.508925] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 14
[ 2593.510039] usb 1-9: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

I've tried updating the system packages, rebooting the PC, booting it with IOMMU disabled via kernel flags but none of these were of any help.

Is there some other magic flag somewhere which would solve the issue?

What might be wrong, and how could I work around it this issue?

Comment: While I'm not sure if this accounts for all the problems, it does seem to be an issue with the USB cable. I wonder if the original cable is shielded properly, for errors occur when I touch the cable. It's designed in such a way that not every USB cable fits - I haven't tried with a different cable yet.

Comment: I have a similar problem with a little Pyle mixer (audio interface) - it's so frustrating! At times it seems like static. I traded cables to no effect. Just now I noticed is that my problems were lessened (maybe disappeared? ) when I turned off my audio interface's phantom power. So I wonder if my issue is current-related. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not Ubuntu-related, after all.

For me, everything has been working smoothly ever since I replaced the USB cable with a high-quality cable (cut the plastic a bit, to make it fit).

**Edit:**

Thanks to Jeff's comment, I realized that during these tests, I always had phantom power enabled but forgot to mention it. Perhaps the original cable would've worked fine with phantom power disabled.

I don't think it would be current-related, because phantom power should be low (just 4 mA) on current. It should be around 200 mW, compared to the total power consumption ~2.5 W of my audio interface. With improper grounding (bad cable), I guess in my case it might've been that the internal phantom power supply somehow interfered with the USB circuitry. I wonder if they use a switching converter for converting from 5 V to 48 V.

Comment: This is interesting - I get an "xhci_hcd ERROR unknown event type 37" running a TASCAM US122L audio intrface which also has phantom power; however I get "underrun"s and "WARN Event TRB for slot 1 ep 3 with no TDs queued" and a "ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD" - doesn't seem like quite the same problem.

Comment: My KOMPLETE Audio 1 died last year. Apparently it was sensitive to static electricity and this fried the electronics. I have had no such errors, warnings nor issues with Ubuntu and Yamaha AG03 yet, regardless of phantom power.